# Forwarding Host header to the origin resulted in SignatureDoesNotMatch error thrown from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I encountered a really strange issue lately when using Amazon CloudFront, and I couldn't figure out why. Here is my setup:

- S3 bucket (A) with OAI s3:GetObject configured in the bucket policy
- CloudFront with S3 origin (A) and trusted signer configured to restrict viewer access

So far so good. It's a pretty simple and straightforward setup. Now here comes the weird part.

**If I forward `Host` header to the origin (in this case bucket A), then the CloudFront signed URL would return `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error.**

Does anyone know why this would happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whitelisting the `Host` header with an S3 origin doesn't really make sense except in one possible configuration that also happens to be somewhat dangerous from a security perspective, and is very non-standard.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Actually I was using `forward all headers` option, and I got this error. I did not specifically want to whitelist `Host` header. Why is it dangerous?

Comment: Whitelisting the `Host` header or all headers when the origin is S3 allows a malicious user to create a bucket with the bucket name `dzzzexample.cloudfront.net` (matching the hostname assigned to your distribution, including the dots) and access it through your CloudFront distribution at your expense, potentially creating a CORS bypass mechanism if you also have an origin that generates any dynamic content.  With an S3 origin, there isn't a reason I can think of to forward all headers, either.  What's your motivation?

Comment: I got the same error SignatureDoesNotMatch trying to forward  'All viewer headers' in origin request settings of CloudFront, however using 'Include the following headers' option and setting  specific 'Referer' header worked fine.